# Function definitions are not permitted in this context when using arrayfun in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following code to create 100 networks. Each network corresponds to a directory. For each directory, i.e., for each network, we call the function arrayfun to sample a fraction of the nodes of the given network, (since we need to do this a number of times, so here we use the function arrayfun). Now, when I run this code, I got the error, saying that the function definitions are not permitted in this context with respect to arrayfun. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? Moreover, is there any better way to do this instead of the arrayfun? Many thanks.

```
clear;
global seq_len
global dir_name
seq_len =100;
[X,Y] = meshgrid( 0 : seq_len-1, 0 : seq_len-1 );
dst_mtr = abs( Y-X );
dst_mtr = arrayfun( @get_distance, dst_mtr)
k = randperm(seq_len);
fraction_vec = 0.9 : -0.1 :0;
n_smpled_nodes_vec = round (fraction_vec * seq_len);
n_networks = 200;

for i=1:n_networks % i is the currendt network label
    dir_name = strcat ('network', num2str(i));
    mkdir (dir_name);
    arrayfun(@get_sampling, n_smpled_nodes_vec);
end
```

Comment: Usually that error means you've defined a function within a script.  Is `get_sampling` defined above the `for`-loop in the same script file?

Comment: No. 'get_sampling' is defined in another 'm' file with name 'get_sampling' in the same directory as the orginal file. Many thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Then I think a minimum working example of code that reproduces your error is need to proceed further.  I don't think I've ever seen that error stem from `arrayfun`.

Comment: Have you tested `get_sampling`?

Comment: I'm with @rlbond here.  I think the problem stems from `get_sampling` and not `arrayfun`.  Could you review/test/post the `get_sampling` function?

Comment: Yes. You guys are correct. I found the bug and fixed it. Many thanks for your time and attention. I appreciate that.